# WP_Query based on 's' and tax_queries

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have a search form for CPT. Basically search use `'s'` parameter of `WP_Query` args. 
`$args['s'] = $search_title;`
It works pretty nice, but I need to extend search results by searching in taxonomies name. Taxonomies which are related with this CPT. The main question is how to search by `'s'` parameter and in taxonomies independently?

I've did a separate `WP_Query` for terms searching, but in final query appears dublicates, bugs like Quering of `post` type, ignoring of `posts__in` and etc. May be there is any easier and clear way to make this? That also will make this without bugs.

```
$args2 = $args;//'post_type' => 'app', 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page
    unset($args2['s']);

$taxonomy_terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'app-category',
    'name__like' => $search_title,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
) );

$term_list = array();
foreach( $taxonomy_terms as $term ) {
    $term_list[] = $term->slug;
    $cat_search = true;
}


$tag_terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'app-tag',
    'name__like' => $search_title,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
) );

$tag_list = array();
foreach( $tag_terms as $tag ) {
    $tag_list[] = $tag->slug;
    $cat_search = true;
}   

$args['fields'] = 'ids';

$args2['fields'] = 'ids';
$args2['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'app-tag',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $tag_list,
    ),
);

$app_posts_x = new WP_Query($args);
wp_reset_postdata();

$tag_app_posts = new WP_Query($args2);
wp_reset_postdata();
$clean_posts_ids = array();


$clean_posts_ids = array_unique(array_merge($app_posts_x->posts, 
$tag_app_posts->posts));

$app_posts_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'any', 
    'posts__in' => $clean_posts_ids,
    'posts_per_page' => $data_limit,
);

$app_posts = new WP_Query($app_posts_args);
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239760/modifying-searchform-php-and-search-php-to-have-two-kinds-of-searches

Comment: @Pim, thank you for you comment, but this doesn't helped me. Search should be proceeded by input in post titles and among taxonomies. Preferable is to find among CPT's content also, but for now I'm trying to figure out even subject